# How to proxy and rewrite a URL like /app/(wildcard)/(actually path for rewriting)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to rewrite and proxy all URLs like ...

```
http://foo.com/app/groupA/index.html
http://foo.com/app/groupB/index.html
```

to

```
http://foo.com:8080/index.html
```

Note how groupA and groupB URLs rewrite to the same place.

I've tried many things, this I think should most likely work because it matches everything after the third occurrence of a `/`.

```
location /app {
  rewrite (?:.*?\/){3}(.*) /$1 break;
  index index.html index.htm;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_redirect    off;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;  
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
  proxy_buffering  off; # buffering would break CouchDB's _changes feed
  proxy_read_timeout 600s;
  proxy_send_timeout 600s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
}
```

Yet on port 8080 I'm not seeing other requests come in. Note, I do see requests when I write...

```
  location ^~ /app {
    rewrite /app/(.*) /$1 break;
    index index.html index.htm;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
    proxy_buffering  off; # buffering would break CouchDB's _changes feed
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_send_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
  }
```

The requests come in on port 8080 as...

```
 /groupA/index.html
 /groupB/index.html
```

I need to figure out how to get rid of that /groupA/ and /groupB/ part of the URL. Note, I don't actually know what string is going to be between those slashes where the group is. It could be /funnybunny/ for all I know :P.

Comment: Nvm, I am seeing requests come in on port 8080 in the first example, still the same problem though that they contain `/groupA/index.html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where a regular expression contains brace characters `{}` the expression should be enclosed in quotes.

Try:

```
rewrite "(?:.*?\/){3}(.*)" /$1 break;
```